# Perform INSERT OR UPDATE as a single operation with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We are using DynamoDB for counting user actions and an item must be either inserted or updated, depending on whatever it's already exists. The code must also update a counter. Right now we do this with 2 steps:

```
using (var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
{
    var table = Table.LoadTable(client, TableName);
    var item = await table.GetItemAsync(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        // row not exists -> insert & return 1
        var document = new Document();
        document["Id"] = id;
        document["Counter"] = 1;
        await table.PutItemAsync(document);
        return 1;
    }
    // row exists -> increment counter & update
    var counter = item["Counter"].AsInt();
    item["Counter"] = counter + 1;
    await table.UpdateItemAsync(item);
    return counter + 1;
}
```

The problem with the code is that it increases latency times & server load. I would prefer to do this with a single operation. I think this should be possible with [conditional expressions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetItemsExample.html) but I cannot figure out how to do this using .NET SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about incrementing counters yourself, as you could have race conditions if multiple instances of your app can increment the counter. Instead use [DynamoDB Atomic Counters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters). For example, my ruby code calls the UpdateItem API with the following (older) way of incrementing counters:

```
{"counter" => {value: {n: "1"}, action: "ADD"}}
```

The newer way is to use an [Update Expression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement), which I haven't implemented yet. Also, if the counter/item doesn't already exist, it will assume the value is 0 and increment the counter to 1.

Answer (score 0):

you have a race condition in your code. 
it's possible that 2 different worker create the item at the same time.

the recommended pattern for what you are trying to do is:

- create if not exists operation for the item.
- atomic counter update on "Count"

So instead of 3 operations (get, put, update) - that also have a race condition - in this case you will only have 2 operations (and the correct behavior)

hope this helps.